# Trying to get an external library module to work for the first time in python

Tags: python, pip

Not sure what's gone wrong here. I upgraded pip before installing the python-docx module and though it gave me that error, the version changed so I wasn't sure what had gone wrong. My site-packages are red which I read means that they're excluded, but I'm not sure what that means for this instance. I've got a screenshot of what's going down in both cmd and pycharm:

[image: external module problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try Running cmd as administrator, Clearly it says "Access Denied". Are you logged in on an Admin user Account in Windows?

Try Right Clicking and open the CMD with Admin Privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have 2 runtime of python.

Lets call them A and B.

You have installed the external lib under runtime A but you try to consume it under runtime B.

A - is under "AppData"

B - is "venv"

Comment: how could I consolidate the two?

Comment: Make sure you install the lib on both OR make sure you use the runtime where the lib is installed